# User cannot access folder he has rights to (Win 2019)

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have a weird situation in which user can not connect to shared folder on Windows Server 2019 (SMB) that has security group with him in it added.

There are 6-7 other folders with same situation and he can normally access and work in them, but this one.

What could I use to check/test what is at hand? - The response from Mac is that the user doesn't have rights to folder.

thanks

Comment: IIRC, macs like to create hidden files to store meta-information about the folder, perhaps the user doesn't have permission to one or more of these?

Comment: Maybe, but the issue is connection to the share itself. - there was no mac connection at all to the share, so no way it could put mac permissions on the files.

Comment: In that case, have you checked both the permissions on the directory being shared and the permissions on the share itself?

Comment: Permissions are absolutely OK. I checked it today - it is like there is some kind of limit on the amount of connections. I have reset the user password and connected again and when connected to server choosen shares in different order. Now the shares I couldn't connect connected and those that were blocked connected. The number is 6. 6 shares max, and after that no connection. I even added Mac to domain and logged in as the user that has the rights to connect to all and it again stopped on 6 drives.

Comment: Curious.  I can't find anything online to suggest that this is a known problem, though admittedly this is a relatively unusual scenario.  Do you have other Mac users on your network, does the same problem affect them?   Does it affect Windows users?  Do you have another Windows Server version on your network, are you able to set up some test shares to see whether the Mac has the same problem connecting to them?

Comment: Possible workaround: for the seventh share, try connecting to the server using the IP address instead of the name.  That's worth trying anyway, it may provide a clue.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I added shares directly over IP, I can try thru the name. I don't have other macs, tho I do have one I use so I can try with it. Windows users work normally and without issue - I don't have another server, only one 2019 that replaced very old 2003.